# Could this `if` statement generate a Null-Reference Exception ever?

Tags: c#, if-statement, nullreferenceexception, logical-operators

I think my point is clear, under any condition, could this throw null-reference exception? i.e. objecting that e.Result is null while trying to access its `Count` property.

```
if (e.Result == null || e.Result.Count == 0)
    return;
```

**EDIT:** To gain the most of this question (for later-coming askers), how will we prevent that exception from happening, can we use `lock` statement? how?

Comment: The answer to your latter two questions is (1) yes, and (2) it depends. Suppose you build the right locks and manage to get "count" without crashing. Then you unlock the result and it mutates to have a *different* count.  **What are you going to do with the now-inaccurate count you just successfully captured?** It seems dangerous to do anything with an incorrect count. There's no point in giving *general* advice for multithreading scenarios; give us a *realistic* scenario and we can advise.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That code can throw a NullReferenceException only if the method is not thread safe. Meaning, if another thread decides to assign null to `e.Result` at coincidentally the exact moment after your `e.Result == null` check and right before your `e.Result.Count == 0` check.

Comment: @marcind yes, but the question was about `e.Result` not `e` itself.

Answer (score 3):

It will only do so if e is null.

Answer (score 1):

```
e == null
```

OR

> Multithreading & race condition ?

Comment: `e` can't be `null` since it is an event handler, not called manually.

Comment: @LordCover just because the variable is named `e` does not imply that it's an event handler :)

Comment: @marcind, I know that :), but I am the developer here, I'm telling ya, it is from an event handler.

Answer (score 1):

No. - e.Result ==null will be evaluated first, if it is true then return will be called immediately and the second case will not be evaluated. It may be have differently in threading

Comment: Without considering multi-threads, I thought this is the case.

Answer (score 1):

It might throw "Null-Reference Exception" if `Result` has its own code behind it and that code is failing with that error.

Answer (score 0):

```
            EventArgs args = e;
            if (args.Result == null || args.Result.Count == 0)
            {
                return;
            }
```

The idea is that you first copy the event args ( e )  into your own local element and use this for the if conditional check. Be careful to ensure that the copy is deep enough to copy the Result also ( otherwise you still end up running into the multithreading case when another thread has just nulled the result midway through the if check ). A local copy is always threadsafe.

Comment: But the local copy is a reference to the original one, right? and it would be affected by what's applied on its original object.

Comment: It wont be affected by some code that changes the reference  'e' ( for example , some external code ' e = null ' will not set the local copy args to null ) but it will be definitely affected by the code that manipulates the 'Result' inside the 'e' ( for example , if an external code runs ' e.Result = null ' , then that will definitely set the local copy's Result also to null above ) .. Thats why I added the remark : Make sure to do a deep copy ( My code above may not reflect a deep copy , but thats the idea )

Comment: Why not copy e.Result instead?

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the multithreading/race-condition issue that others have already pointed out, the topic you might be looking for is **[short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).** In C#, the `||` operator uses short-circuiting (as opposed to `|`, which is eager), so if `e.Result == null` evaluates to true, the `e.Result.Count == 0` won't be evaluated.

Others have answered already but I wanted to give you the name for this type of behavior and some further reading.